# Intermittent 403 Access Not Configured

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am intermittently receiving the following error on two different API Projects.  The API Projects have been functioning normally for nearly a year without change. When the error starts occurring it happens in bursts lasting several minutes, then starts functioning properly again.  The error events happen several times an hour, we noticed the errors happening early last night more than 12+ hours ago.  Any help is appreciated.

API Scopes:
www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?key=*****************: (403) Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem this morning.  Instead of using

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?key=****

You now need to use

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=****

and enable the Google+ API in the admin console.  There might be another way to do this without Google+, but this worked for me!

No idea why this changed - it seemed like the userinfo method was scheduled for deprecation but in a couple months.  You might be able to get some info from Google about the user without Google+, just check the docs.

Comment: Checked the Oauth docs and it doesn't mention it being deprecated. The Google+ docs do mention it will be deprecated in Sept 2014.  Given this I will plan on updating, though it should still function without errors for the time being.

Comment: The semantics of deprecation vs dysfunction aside, userinfo does't work, and the Google+ method does.  But if you can solve the problem without G+, that would be awesome!