# Google OAuth 2 "accessNotConfigured" error

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

Last night a site that has been working fine for about six months started getting a 403 error when using Google OAuth. The authentication code hasn't changed, and I don't see any notes that Google OAuth suddenly changed either. I've tried re-issuing the client ID (including client secret) but that didn't fix it.

Details:

- Full error: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project." comes after this (scrubbed) request:

  ```
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fx.y.com%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&client_id=12345-abcdefg.apps.googleusercontent.com
  ```

  The response header does contain this (scrubbed):

  ```
  Location:   https://x.y.com/auth/google/callback?code=4/MF-V...
  ```

  which contains the code similar to what I see in the API playground.
- Server setup: node.js running express with passport/passport-google-oauth.

I don't know what API needs to be enabled -- I sort of think this is a miss-sense error. None of the APIs in the "APIs & auth" section of the Developers Console appear to be relevant. I'm configuring OAuth under "APIs & auth > Credentials." This is not youtube or Google+ authentication.

Comment: I'm running into a very similar problem.  I'm wondering if Google is deprecating things sooner than they documented...

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640094/intermittent-403-access-not-configured/22642747#22642747  Not totally sure if its relevant to what you're doing but it might be helpful.

Comment: Someone please help, I am having the same issue. Please post a solution someone!!

Comment: This seems to be an intermittent issue. As I was going to activate the APIs suggested in user3461234's answer below, the API started working again. Shrug. @James your idea seems believable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the cause of your problem but you should be aware of it anyway. [Using OAuth 2.0 for Login (early version)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2LoginV1)

> Important: Google has deprecated the early implementation of OAuth 2.0
>   for login that is described in this document and will no longer
>   support it, after a migration period. If your app uses OAuth 2.0 login
>   (early version), you should either switch to Google+ Sign-In or update
>   your existing userinfo endpoints and scopes by the deadline given in
>   the migration timetable. For instructions, see Migrate or update OAuth
>   2.0 login.

Migration timetable says on Sept. 1, 2014 its gone: https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable

Answer (score -1):

We are having the same issues.  I don't know if it is luck - or what, but a few minutes ago i finally started just enabling API's to see if it would help.  I enabled Google+ Domains API, Google+ Hangouts API, Admin SDK.  After not being about to login all day (same error that you were getting).  I have logged in twice now.

Comment: This is not an answer or solution.

Comment: @MichalS no its not but users with low rep cant post comments. There only option is to post it as an answer.

Comment: True, try gain some, it's not so hard :) Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: To allow G+ is just enough. Than wait 10 minutes to get worked.